# How to handle small file issue in NiFi

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

I'm referring  this below article;

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Create-Dynamic-Partitions-based-on-FlowFile-Con...

I'm trying to create pipeline in nifi while data coming realtime streaming based say some example kafka, while data put in hdfs in partitioned location, it may ended be with many small files at the same while querying im facing performance lag issue; can you please give some apporaches to resolve small files issue in nifi itself with orc file format;